# decimal to hexadecimal in c# with mistake "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

Tags: c#, hex, decimal

My code is quite simple:

```
string aveint = "aveint";
otdr_Portobject.WriteLine(aveint +int_averagesCon.Value.ToString("X2")+ "\n");
```

`otdr_Portobject` is a COM Port.

`int_averagesCon` is a NumericUpDown with Value 64.

when i run the programm, there is alway a messagebox showing:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Someone know why I keep getting this error?

Comment: which is the stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "X2" format specified is only supported by integral types.

NumericUpDown.Value is a decimal.

You need to first convert your decimal value to an integral type, e.g.:

```
Convert.ToInt32(int_averagesCon.Value).ToString("X2")+ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
otdr_Portobject.WriteLine(aveint +((byte)int_averagesCon.Value).ToString("X2")+ "\n");
```

This would create a `byte` value from the `double` first and then try formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use X2 (binary format) with decimal type.

Easy solution would be to cast decimal to integer and that call to string.

```
decimal x = 64;
((int)x).ToString("X2");
```